# basis for subspace of set of transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given $S$ a subspace of the set of linear transformations $T : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $T(x) = ax$ for some scalar $a$,  how do you find the basis for $S$?

Comment: Is this for all $x$?

Answer (score 1):

The set $\{T\}$ where $Tx:= x$ is a basis. It is linearly indepedent because it only contains one element which is nonzero. And it is clearly spanning.

Comment: This is is not a spanning set. The space S is 2 dimensional. The basis should be the identity and also the projetion onto the span of $x$.

Comment: Why isn't it spanning? I must be confused. For take the map $T'(x) = ax$. Then $T' = aT$.

Comment: Well it depends on if the OP means $T(x)=ax$ for all $x$ or for one specific $x$.

Comment: OK my interpretation was $S := \{ x \mapsto ax : a \in \mathbb{R}\}.$

Answer (score 0):

You can use base vector transformations to solve this, if space of the vectors/matrices $x$ can be described with a base then all you have to do to get the base of S is:

Base of the space of all $x\in R_2$: $B_1=\{e_1,e_2\}$ then calculate:

$f_1=T(e_1)$

$f_2=T(e_2)$

And now you have the base of subspace S:

$B_2=\{f_1,f_2\}$.